# Error lldb_expr when printing a variable

Tags: arrays, swift, enums, swift-playground

In the following code, because I get an error when printing "aMovie.moviesGenere" in playground:

```
struct Movie: Codable {
    enum MovieGenere: String, Codable {
        case horror, skifi, comedy, adventure, animation
    }

    var name : String
    var moviesGenere : [MovieGenere]
    var rating : Int
}

let aMovie = Movie(name: "Up", moviesGenere: [.comedy , .adventure, .animation], rating : 4)

print(aMovie.moviesGenere)
```

The error:

```
[__lldb_expr_98.Movie.MovieGenere.comedy, __lldb_expr_98.Movie.MovieGenere.adventure, __lldb_expr_98.Movie.MovieGenere.animation]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s **not** an error, it´s the **Low Level Debugger** and how the Playground prints out your enum. If you break it down you´ll see:
[
 __lldb_expr_98.**`Movie.MovieGenere.comedy`**,
__lldb_expr_98.**`Movie.MovieGenere.adventure`**, 
  __lldb_expr_98.**`Movie.MovieGenere.animation`**
]

Comment: Thank you for your response, then to be able to access the values I can use a For- in

Comment: @MarioBurga, well you have the values there but if you use this `for movie in aMovie.moviesGenere {
    print(movie)
}` You´ll print out `//comedy
//adventure
//animation`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove __lldb_expr prefix from your console output. then struct must conforms to CustomStringConvertible protocol. This is a public protocol, it has a var description where we can provide custom string to display struct description.

```
struct Movie: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    enum MovieGenere: String, Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
        var description: String {
            return self.rawValue
        }

        case horror, skifi, comedy, adventure, animation
    }

    var name : String
    var moviesGenere : [MovieGenere]
    var rating : Int

    var description: String {
        return "\(name), \(moviesGenere), \(rating)"
    }
}

let aMovie = Movie(name: "Up", moviesGenere: [.comedy , .adventure, .animation], rating : 4)
print(aMovie)
```